# В IntelliJ Idea пропали в настройках Indexed Maven repositories

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

В **IntelliJ Idea** пропали в настройках **Indexed Maven repositories**.

На панели **Maven Projects** ничего не отображается

(ни плагины, ни зависимости... вообще ничего)

в **Event log** сообщение: `Unable to import maven project: See logs for details`
[image: ошибки]

Как сделать так, чтобы вернуть Indexed Maven repositories на место  и избавиться от указанных проблем?

**UPD:**
в логах Idea - следующее:

```
2015-08-18 15:47:42,856 [1773549]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - "D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\jre\jre\bin\java" -Djava.awt.headless=true -Didea.version==14.1.4 -Xmx1024m; -Didea.maven.embedder.version=3.3.3 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 -classpath "/D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3/lib/resources_en.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\log4j.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\jdom.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\annotations.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\oromatcher.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\picocontainer.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\util.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\jna.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\trove4j.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\resources_en.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\jna-utils.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\lucene-core-2.4.1.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven-server-api.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-common.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\archetype-catalog-2.2.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\archetype-common-2.2.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\maven-dependency-tree-1.2.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\nexus-indexer-3.0.4.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\nexus-indexer-artifact-1.0.1.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven32-server-impl.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\aether-api-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\aether-connector-basic-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\aether-impl-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\aether-spi-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\aether-transport-wagon-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\aether-util-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\aopalliance-1.0.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\cdi-api-1.0.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\commons-cli-1.2.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\commons-io-2.2.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\commons-lang-2.6.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\guava-18.0.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\javax.inject-1.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\jsoup-1.7.2.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\jsr250-api-1.0.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-aether-provider-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-artifact-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-builder-support-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-compat-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-core-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-embedder-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-model-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-model-builder-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-plugin-api-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-repository-metadata-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-settings-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-settings-builder-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.0.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.0.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\plexus-cipher-1.7.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\sisu-guice-3.2.5-no_aop.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\wagon-file-2.9.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\wagon-http-2.9-shaded.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\wagon-http-shared-2.9.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\wagon-provider-api-2.9.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer 
2015-08-18 15:47:42,886 [1773579]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. 
2015-08-18 15:47:42,886 [1773579]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. 
2015-08-18 15:47:42,886 [1773579]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx1024m; 
2015-08-18 15:47:42,910 [1773603]   INFO - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - "D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\jre\jre\bin\java" -Djava.awt.headless=true -Didea.version==14.1.4 -Xmx1024m; -Didea.maven.embedder.version=3.3.3 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 -classpath "/D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3/lib/resources_en.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\log4j.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\jdom.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\annotations.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\oromatcher.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\picocontainer.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\util.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\jna.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\trove4j.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\resources_en.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\lib\jna-utils.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\lucene-core-2.4.1.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven-server-api.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-common.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\archetype-catalog-2.2.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\archetype-common-2.2.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\maven-dependency-tree-1.2.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\nexus-indexer-3.0.4.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3-server-lib\nexus-indexer-artifact-1.0.1.jar;D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven32-server-impl.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\aether-api-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\aether-connector-basic-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\aether-impl-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\aether-spi-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\aether-transport-wagon-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\aether-util-1.0.2.v20150114.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\aopalliance-1.0.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\cdi-api-1.0.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\commons-cli-1.2.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\commons-io-2.2.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\commons-lang-2.6.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\guava-18.0.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\javax.inject-1.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\jsoup-1.7.2.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\jsr250-api-1.0.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-aether-provider-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-artifact-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-builder-support-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-compat-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-core-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-embedder-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-model-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-model-builder-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-plugin-api-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-repository-metadata-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-settings-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\maven-settings-builder-3.3.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.0.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.0.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\plexus-cipher-1.7.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\sisu-guice-3.2.5-no_aop.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\wagon-file-2.9.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\wagon-http-2.9-shaded.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\wagon-http-shared-2.9.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\lib\wagon-provider-api-2.9.jar;c:\apache_maven_3.3.3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer 
2015-08-18 15:47:42,935 [1773628]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. 
2015-08-18 15:47:42,935 [1773628]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. 
2015-08-18 15:47:42,935 [1773628]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx1024m; 
2015-08-18 15:47:42,935 [1773628]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Cannot reconnect. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.applyProfiles(MavenServerManager.java:518)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.applyProfiles(MavenProjectReader.java:369)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.doReadProjectModel(MavenProjectReader.java:98)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.readProject(MavenProjectReader.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProject.read(MavenProject.java:635)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.doUpdate(MavenProjectsTree.java:564)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.doAdd(MavenProjectsTree.java:509)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.update(MavenProjectsTree.java:470)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.updateAll(MavenProjectsTree.java:441)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessorReadingTask.perform(MavenProjectsProcessorReadingTask.java:60)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.doProcessPendingTasks(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:134)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.access$100(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:30)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor$2.run(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:109)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil$6.run(MavenUtil.java:441)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start maven service; nested exception is: 
    com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx1024m;

    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:166)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:71)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$9.execute(MavenServerManager.java:521)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$9.execute(MavenServerManager.java:518)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx1024m;

    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:146)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:163)
    ... 26 more
2015-08-18 15:47:42,936 [1773629]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4  Build #IU-141.1532.4 
2015-08-18 15:47:42,936 [1773629]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - JDK: 1.8.0_40 
2015-08-18 15:47:42,936 [1773629]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 
2015-08-18 15:47:42,936 [1773629]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2015-08-18 15:47:42,936 [1773629]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - OS: Windows 7 
2015-08-18 15:47:42,936 [1773629]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Last Action: Maven.Reimport
```

**UPD:** 
этот же проект на другом компьютере нормально отображается в MavenProjects (помечен как 3 на картинке), там и плагины отображаются, и зависимости... и вообще Idea воспринимает его, как Мавен проект.

---

**Решение, которое  мне помогло**

---

- Удалил **IntelliJ Idea**
- Удалил все настройки **IntelliJ Idea** (.IntelliJIdea14 в папке пользователя)
- Удалил папку с конфигурацией Maven (.m2 в папке пользователя)
- Установил заново **IntelliJ Idea**

Все заработало!

*Спасибо, коллеги за ответы!*

Comment: А что в логе? (<SYSTEM DRIVE>\Users\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.IdeaIC14\system\log)

Comment: @maxwell, я добавил в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ошибке, не возможно создать JVM из-за некорректного размера хипа.

```
 Caused by: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
 Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
 Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx1024m;
```

Необходимо зайти в раздел Build Tools->Maven->Importing и проверить VM options for importer (см. скриншот) Возможно некорректно указан параметр (кириллица) или не хватает оперативной памяти. [image: Скриншот настроек IDEA]

Comment: к сожалению нет.    -Xmx1024m; латинскими символами (я проверил)

Comment: Точка с запятой только в ответе? В параметрах ее не должно быть. Попробуйте поставить меньше (512 или 256), возможно незарезервированной памяти меньше гигабайта

Comment: спасибо.  Памяти хватает... точка с запятой допускается (это разделитель если используется несколько параметров)... мне помогла переустановка Idea и сброс настроек.... может и не самое изящное решение...но работает.

Comment: Согласно [документации](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/maven-importing.html) для разделения параметров используется пробел, как и при других указаниях параметров JVM: 
**Use spaces to separate individual options, for example, -client -ea -Xmx1024m.**

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ответу на английском SO, проблема в резолюции сетки, добавьте

`127.0.0.1 localhost`
в файл `<SYSTEM_DRIVE>:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

[Ссылка на оригинальный тред в английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701347/unable-to-import-maven-project-into-intellij-idea)